# Paging 3.0 handle Api and Network error using clean architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, clean-architecture, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3

> I am following uncle bob clean architecture to some extent and for that I have to implement UseCase Interactor and  Repository pattern for Implementing Paging 3.0.

I haven't find any example that handle `network response code` and `Api Error` with Paging.
I am building a Gallery app that can fetch images from multiple sources like Unsplash or Pixabay and map **PagingData** to my **PagingData**.

I want to know where can I handle **ApiResponse** and `Network Error` **FetchPhotoUseCase.kt**

In order to handle **ApiResponse**, I have created below class

```
sealed class ApiResponse<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : ApiResponse<T>()
    data class Error(val errorMessage: String) : ApiResponse<Nothing>()
    object Empty : ApiResponse<Nothing>()
}
```

**PhotoRepository.kt**

```
interface PhotoRepository {
    fun searchPhotos(queryString: String): Flow<PagingData<PhotoBO>>
}
```

**PhotoRepositoryImpl.kt**

```
class PhotoRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val unsplashApi: UnsplashApi
) :PhotoRepository{
    override fun searchPhotos(queryString: String): Flow<PagingData<PhotoBO>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 20,
                maxSize = 100,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { UnsplashPagingSource(unsplashApi, queryString) }
        ).flow.mapLatest { pagingData ->
            pagingData.map {
                it.toPhotoBO()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FetchPhotoUseCase.kt**

```
class FetchPhotoUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val photoRepository: PhotoRepository
) : UseCaseWithParams<String,Flow<PagingData<PhotoBO>>>()
{
    override suspend fun buildUseCase(params: String): Flow<PagingData<PhotoBO>> {
        return photoRepository.searchPhotos(params)
    }
}
```

What if there isn't any network connected or api fail due to any reason. I want to know how and at which layer I have to handle those errors

> At which level ApiResponse is handle and how to implement it in clean architecture..